# How to make RSS subscribers read old RSS items again?

Tags: rss

Suppose I wrote some code to generate an `RSS` for a web site. A few `RSS` readers subscribed to the `RSS`.

Suppose I updated the `RSS` generating code and now my `RSS` changed. The `RSS` subscribers though still display the "old" `RSS` since they didn't read the `RSS` again.

Now I wonder how to make the `RSS` subscribers "refresh" the `RSS` items. Can I add a tag/field to the `RSS` to make the subscribers read the old `RSS` items again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your safest option is to make new entries with a new `<guid>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/164595/989257. Also updating titles or content could make some readers consider the old entries as new/unread.

Comment: I am afraid that changing `guid` will make duplicates. Does it make sense ?

Comment: It probably will make duplicates, but It will also guarantee that rss readers see the items as new. Instead you could just try to update title and description tags.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am afraid the duplicates are even worse :(